# Retrieve query for time range (FetchXML/QueryExpression)

Tags: datetime, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

(Sorry for bad English)
I have an application that uses MS-CRM 2011 Web Service for retrieving last changes on crm Entities. This application Sync last data changes with a Windows Mobile device.
Sync operation occurs periodic every 20 minutes. In each sync operation I want to retrieve  changes occurred from previous update by checking entities 'modifiedon' field.
Problem is that, CRM queries don't use Time piece of DateTime object and all change from the start of passed DateTime parameter been returned.

I'd check both FetchXML and QueryExpression, there is no different.
Is there any way to create a query for run on Crm WebService that return modified record from specified Date and time?

Sample (My FetchXml) :

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
<entity name='new_brand'>
<attribute name='new_brandname' />
<attribute name='new_pdanumber' />
<filter type='and'>
<condition attribute='modifiedon' operator='on-or-after' value='2012/11/12 23:59'/>
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

See In the code, I wants all modified entities from 2012/11/12 23:00, but crm returns all modified record from 2012/11/12 00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've added a new field (called ModifiedOnTick) to the Entity, and record the time difference in milliseconds with a fixed date (2011-01-01) in this field.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem now with and oldest Dynamics CRM 2011 organization.The on or after comparation don't compare the time, only the date. Try using grater or equal ('ge' in fetchxml).

Comment: We've added a new field (called ModifiedOnTick) to the Entity, and record the time difference in milliseconds with a fixed date (2011-01-01) in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for records changed on or after 23:59... Your documented results sound correct.

In any case, the time part *is* used but i suspect you are seeing the result of user time versus universal time. If the users time zone offset != 0 then midnight as selected by the user in the UI will be different to the value stored in the database which is the UST equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. '23:59' is a sample to show CRM don't use Time and all records changed before this time (on selected date) would return . I need a query (or Advanced Find) that can get entities modified between two time in one day. (In previous sample changed entities between 2012/11/12 00:00 to 2012/11/12 23:58 should not be in result set)

Comment: May be I have to create a Custom Workflow and create a new field for my entity (like ModifiedOnTicks), when entity 'modifiedon' field changes, workflow runs and calculate its value Ticks and store on that field, But seems this will become a loop.

Comment: You're right about Time being ignored ([see here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/crmdevelopment/thread/c5083689-65fb-474f-a7bc-2eff393016fe)). Regarding maintaining Ticks - if you put that in a pre-create and pre-update plug-in you could inject the value as part of the transaction thereby not causing a subsequent update, Hope that makes sense...!

Comment: Another option assuming that you are in custom code is to filter your results again in .Net _after_ CRM has returned the results that ignore Time?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's better to filter results in .Net, I can sort result by ModifiedOn field and adding entities to my collection one by one until next entity ModifiedOn passes from requested time, Thanks